# error: package io.agora.rtm does not exist

Tags: agora.io

Download git code and run Agora-RTM-Tutorial-Android project getting error

package io.agora.rtm does not exist getting this error message on all java file when import io.agora.rtm does not exist

Comment: Did you import the Agora RTM SDK? https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/release_android_rtm?platform=Android

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the SDK and import the files to the cloned Project. Follow the steps described [in the github page](https://github.com/AgoraIO/RTM/tree/master/Agora-RTM-Tutorial-Android#integration-mode)